# Filter child elements, but keep the original structure with XPath

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, filter, xquery

How can i get from this:

```
<a id="1">
    <b>
        <c type="1"/>
        <c type="0"/>
        <c type="0"/>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c type="1"/>
        <c type="0"/>
        <c type="1"/>
    </b>
</a>
<a id="2">
    <b>
        <c type="1"/>
        <c type="1"/>
        <c type="0"/>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c type="1"/>
        <c type="1"/>
    </b>
</a>
```

the following:

```
<a id="1">
    <b>
        <c type="1"/>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c type="1"/>
        <c type="1"/>
    </b>
</a>
<a id="2">
    <b>
        <c type="1"/>
        <c type="1"/>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c type="1"/>
        <c type="1"/>
    </b>
</a>
```

So i want to filter the  elements, but keep the original structure. I use sql server.
I tried some variation but none of those has worked like i expected.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Where `@x` is your xml...

```
set  @x.modify('delete (/a/b/c[@type="0"])')
```